# Performance problem importing data into MariaDB 10.3

Tags: import, mariadb, partitioning

I am trying to partition some large InnoDB tables in MariaDB 10.3. Inserting data into these tables takes several hours for each table. This seems excessively slow.

These tables were originally built in MySQL 5.5 and recently upgraded to MariaDB 10.3. There were no reported errors or warnings with this upgrade process.

The tables hold on average about 24 Million rows with about 600 Mb of data per table.

Partitioning these tables followed this procedure:

1. Make an empty copy of the target table partitioned by range (on a datetime column) with two partitions, one to hold data older than a defined date and a future column partitioned to hold data less than MAXVALUE.
2. Create 100 weekly partitions in this empty table.
3. Insert data into this table through a select statement:

   INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * from originalTable;

The version of MariaDB I am using is 10.3.9

Global variables are default values except:

```
autocommit = OFF
global_max_allowed_packet = 1073741824
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10737418240
innodb_doublewrite = OFF
```

This is running on CentOS Version 7.2.1511 with 65GB Memory and 40 3G cores.

I read on the web that imports of 300Mb taking a few minutes but I can not even come close to that speed. My performance seems like something is terribly wrong but I can not identify an issue. Any ideas on how I can speed this up are greatly appreciated?

Comment: I know autocommit is off but have you tried wrapping it in a BEGIN/COMMIT?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to `PARTITION` lots of tables?  Partitioning, contrary to obvious wisdom, does *not* provide any intrinsic performance benefit.

Did you attempt `ALTER TABLE .. ADD PARTITION ....`?  That *might* be faster than using `INSERT .. SELECT`, though I suspect the underlying actions may be the same.

`OriginalTable` has 24 million (or so) rows, correct?  (It will be a single transaction.)

You mentioned lots of cores; are you attempting to user more than one?

If there are several such tables, you will end up with hundreds of partitions.  Each partition is effectively a separate "table", thereby needing `table_open_cache`, etc, values to be increased.

It is typical for the indexes on a partitioned table to need to be different than the indexes on the non-partitioned equivalent.  Did you take that into account?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I cautioned that partitioning the tables would not necessarily improve performance which is their goal. I have not attempted altering the existing table as it seemed this method would minimize the downtime. However, it took over 11 hours to insert data into one of these tables. This glacial pace seems to indicate there is a major issue with the configuration or setup of this machine, but I do not see what it is. When loading one table it appears to fork 4 threads to perform the IO operations.

Comment: @KirtHall - Technically, yes, there are extra threads for I/O.  These are shared among all InnoDB connections.  Still, there is only one row being processed in the `ALTER` or `INSERT` at a time.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before the conversion and after.  And if practical, some of the queries.  I will be happy to critique the conversion to partitioning -- pointing out pitfalls, index changes needed, etc.

Comment: @KirtHall - And meanwhile, you can argue that the technical detals in adding the partitioning justifies not doing the partitioning.  Tell 'them' that there may be other avenues to pursue to improve performance.